# Carregar constante

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails4

Estou com problema para instancia o model Report.

Console:

```
LoadError (Unable to autoload constant Report_questao, expected app/models/report.rb to define it):
  app/controllers/pessoas_controller.rb:49:in `reportar'
```

controller:

```
require 'report'

class QuestoesController < ApplicationController
def reportar
    @report = report.new
  end
end
```

Model:

report.rb

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :pessoa

end
```

Comment: O Erro parece ser na Model Report se tiver como postar ela ai pra gente

Answer (score 0):

O erro idiota tava em:

```
questao.new
```

ao invés de

```
Questao.new
```

obrigado Marco Vinicius